# vim command to add a semi colon at the end of all lines in a file beginning with a pattern

Tags: vim

I would like to insert a semi-colon at the end of all the lines beginning with some pattern(MATCH_) in a file.
Whats the command to use.

Comment: VIM editor command is what I wanted.

Comment: I would recommend taking some time to learn the basics of regular expressions. This way you'd be able to construct your own, it's really quite simple once you know the rules. [Here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_patterns) is a decent start, [here](http://www.vimregex.com/) is a rather throrough overview with examples, and, as always, there's built-in help, in case of regexps it's `:help pattern`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the `:g` command:

`:g/^<pattern>/normal A;`

A bit of an explanation:

This finds all lines starting with (due to the `^`) the specified `<pattern>` and then executes the command `normal A;` which switches to normal mode, then does `A` to append to the line, followed by typing `;`.

Comment: I want to search for all lines in a file using %s and insert a seimi-colon if its matching a pattern in VIM :   %s/MATCH_.*$/&;  But this adds a semi-colon at the end of all the lines that begins with the pattern MATCH_ even though the line matching the pattern ends with a semi-colon. How can I change this command to add a semi-colon only if the line beginning with the pattern "MATCH_" doesnt terminate with a semi-colon.